# Issue while installing Apache with yum

Tags: linux, repository, redhat

When I run `yum install httpd-devel` I get this :

```
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7Server&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=$infra error was
14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org; Erreur inconnue"


 One of the configured repositories failed (Inconnu),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:


Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base/7Server/x86_64
```

I'm using rhel 7 how can I solve this?

Comment: get a subscription or switch from RHEL7 to CENTOS7

Answer (score 0):

Please download the rpm of repository for CENTOS 7 and RHEL 7

### RHEL/CentOS 7 64-Bit

```
# wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-8.noarch.rpm
# rpm -ivh epel-release-7-8.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: I did install the EPEL repo but the same problem maintains.. !! i got this : `http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden` this link is blocked in my network :/

Answer (score 0):

You must realize that RHEL operating system is not FOSS (free and open-source) like CentOS or Ubuntu. You need to purchase a subscription to use its services like software repository and tech support.

You can have look at their [catalog](https://www.redhat.com/wapps/store/catalog.html) if you want, or you can use CentOS which is derived from RHEL, but is FOSS. Both the operating systems are closely related, and almost everything you can do on RHEL can be done in CentOS.

Comment: I didn't now that i have to purchase a subscription in order to use RHEL repos, thanks a lot.